# Efficient Generation of Random Orthogonal Matrix in Python

Tags: numpy, matrix, orthogonal, dirichlet

I need to generate a lot of random mean-invariant orthogonal matrices for my work. A mean-invariant matrix has the property `A*1_n=1_n`, where 1_n is a vector of size n of the scalar 1, basicaly `np.ones(n)`. I use Python and specifically Numpy to create my matrices, but I want to make sure that my method is both correct and the most efficient. Also, I want to present my findings on 3 separate orthogonalization methods I have tried and hopefully get an explanation on why one method is faster than the others. I ask four questions in the end of the post about my findings.

In general, in order to create a mean-invariant random orthogonal matrix A, you need to create a random square matrix M1, replace its first column with a column of ones and orthogonalize the matrix. Then, you do that again with another matrix M2 and the final mean-invariant random orthogonal matrix is A = M1*(M2.T). The bottleneck of this process is the orthogonalization. There are 3 main ways of orthogonalization, namely the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), which uses projection, the [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation), which uses reflection and the [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

The creation of a nxn random matrix is pretty straight forward with Numpy:
`M1 = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))`.
Then, I replace the first column of M1 with 1_n.

As far as I know the Gram–Schmidt process does not exist in any very popular library, so I found this code which works fine:

```
def gram_schmidt(M1):
    """Orthogonalize a set of vectors stored as the columns of matrix M1."""
    # Get the number of vectors.
    n = M1.shape[1]
    for j in range(n):
        # To orthogonalize the vector in column j with respect to the
        # previous vectors, subtract from it its projection onto
        # each of the previous vectors.
        for k in range(j):
            M1[:, j] -= np.dot(M1[:, k], M1[:, j]) * M1[:, k]
        M1[:, j] = M1[:, j] / np.linalg.norm(M1[:, j])
    return M1
```

Obviously, the above code has to be executed for both M1 and M2.

For a 10,000x10,000 random mean-invariant orthogonal matrix, this process takes about **1 hour** on my computer (8-core @3.7GHz, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD).

I found that instead of the Gram-Schmidt process I could orthogonalize the matrix in Numpy with this:
`q1, r1 = np.linalg.qr(M1)`
where q1 is the orthogonalized matrix and r1 is an upper triangular matrix (we don't need to keep r1). I do the same to M2 and get q2. Then, A=q1*(q2.T). This process for the same 10,000x10,000 matrix takes about **70 seconds** on the same computer. I believe the `linalg.qr()` library uses the Householder transformation, but I would like someone to confirm it.

Finaly, I tried to change the way that the initial random matrices M1 and M2 are produced. Instead of
`M1 = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))` I used the Dirichlet distribution:
`M1 = np.random.default_rng().dirichlet(np.ones(n),size=(n))`.
Then, I used the `linalg.qr()` like before and I got the 10000x10000 matrix in about the same time as `M1 = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))`.

My questions are:

1. Does the Numpy's `np.linalg.qr()` method actually use the Householder transformation? Or possibly the the Givens rotation?
2. Why is the Gram-Schmidt process so much slower than `np.linalg.qr()`?
3. I know that the Dirichlet process produces an almost orthogonal matrix. Is it because we are creating 10,000 dimensions, so it is likely to randomly get a vector that is orthogonal to all others? The `np.linalg.qr()` does not care about how close the matrix is to orthogonality.
4. Is there an even faster way to generate random orthogonal matrices? Are there any optimizations I can make to my code to make it faster/more efficient?

Edit: The cupy's `cp.linalg.qr()` on the same 10,000x10,000 random matrix takes only 16 sec on my 2080ti, instead of 70 sec for numpy on the CPU (8-core @3.7GHz with multithreading, 16GB RAM and 512GB SSD).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method for manufacturing such matrices. I have no idea what the distribution is like, but it might be faster than the methods you describe.

First off, here a householder reflector is a matrix of the form

```
H = I - 2*h*h'/(h'*h)
```

where h is a vector.

Note that:

H is orthogonal, and symmetric

H can be applied to a vector in O(dim)

if x and y are any two vectors with the same norm then we can find such a matrix to map x to y (h is x-y)

One way to manufacture 'random' orthogonal matrices is by computing products of 'random' Householder matrices

If Q is an orthogonal matrix and u is the vector of all 1's and

```
q = Q*u
```

Then q and u have the same norms, so if H is the householder reflector that maps q to u,

```
R = H*Q is orthogonal
R*u = H*Q*u = H*q = u
```